# Get Pandas to plot the actual value on the index of a DataFrame and NOT the frequency in which it occurs

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried many searches and can only find Pandas hist() for frequency.
The thing is, the values in the array ARE the frequencies of certain values. There's no need for the code to find the frequency since the data has meaning (and it's not just raw data). Simply put, the height of the column is the value.

[image: Data]

Here's my current code snippet and what I'm getting.

```
import pandas as pd

size, scale = 1000, 10
commutes = pd.DataFrame({'frequency' : [15.17,4.14,5.52,8.97,13.79,11.73,13.79,26.9]},
                         index = ["A+", "A", "A-", "B,B+", "C,C+", "D,D+", "E", "F"])

ax = commutes.plot.hist(grid=True, bins=8, rwidth=0.9,
                   color='#607c8e')
```

[image: Output Plot]

I'm trying to attain the plot below (from Excel):

[image: Desired Output Plot]

Comment: Your are looking for a bar `ax = commutes.plot.bar(grid=True, color='#607c8e')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a bar plot:

```
commutes.plot.bar()
```

[image: bar plot]